# Integrating parts of a project into another project

Tags: javascript, build, automation, integration

I'm building a library, and plan to use *parts* (could be entire files or arbitrary lines) of other libraries in my code. Also, I would like to have fixes on the other library reflect onto my library as well.

- I could just add the entire library (script tag, AMD, etc.) and use it. But I don't want to use the entire bulk of another library for my very small library. One of these libraries is Modernizr, but I'll only be using at most a dozen checks only.
- I could just copy-paste the implementation from one library to mine. However, when the library I need updates, this would mean copy-paste all over again.
- I read about GIT and submodules, where a subfolder could contain a sub-project. This sounds promising, where a build script could extract parts of the other library and put it into my code. However, the library could have different code structure than mine which would lead to manual editing, which defeats the purpose of some steps.

I haven't gone that deep into automation but I have had basic experience with makefiles. How would one go about in doing such integration?

Answer (score 0):

It's not generally a good idea to use parts of libraries that didn't pre-package those parts for you. The correct way to do it would depend on each library and how it is meant to be made/compiled. There may also be license considerations, which will vary depending on the license of the library, some would require maintaining the license for the part of the library that you use.

[Edit]
Would it be possible to include the entire other libraries, and then use some sort of minification on your library to keep the size down?